# Memory is not released even though I explicitly release it

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am in the process of optimizing my app and making sure memory management is properly implemented. As I found the didUnload / dealloc / willAppear not reliable for implementing my memory cleanup, I decided to implement my own method so I can have full control of this memory  management.

Definition of my arrays in the header file

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *selectedCardIDs;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *selectedRowArray;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *cardArray;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *cardIDArray;
```

Here the release method:

```
- (void) willReleaseObjects {
[self.aCopyOfCardIDArray release];
[self.listOfItems release];
[self.aCopyListOfItems release];
[self.selectedCardIDs release];
[self.selectedRowArray release];
[self.cardArray release];
[self.cardIDArray release];
```

}

The arrays can get very large (> 1'000 entry each), why a release of those arrays is essential after the view is unloaded. I explicitly call this function in the IBAction method, such as:

```
- (IBAction) stopDictionary:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender {
[self closeDatabase];
[self willReleaseObjects];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

I debugged the code and it is actually executing each release, however when I diagnose the memory allocation with Instruments, it seems to free up only partial memory, actually almost nothing why the memory consumption of course is increasing every time I load this view again, which is no good at all. 
Any idea, why my memory is not released here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call release on a property as you risk something very bad happening in case you have any properties declared as assign or copy. You could potentially release a returned instance which is already autoreleased.

Instead either release the instance variable behind it or set the property to nil. Either way you will achieve the correct result. In case you have any Key/Value observers on your properties the best way is to set the properties to nil which will automatically propagate the values to any observers:

```
- (void) willReleaseObjects {
  self.aCopyOfCardIDArray = nil;
  self.listOfItems = nil;
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks Claus, I tried, same result. I added the property definition in my question and as you see do I retain all of them. And to my knowledge all allocated objects should be released using release. At least that is what I have read so far about memory management. I somehow have the impression, that the content of that entire viewController is not destroyed, after I return to the previous view.

Comment: You may need to inspect any other places that you access these properties and make sure that you don't have an extra retain somewhere. Also make sure that don't leak it when you create the properties. E.g. this will cause a leak: self.property = [[AClass alloc] init]; Anyway, the method I described will not cause the leaks.

Comment: Resolved. Forgot the autorelease on the alloc. Objects are now being released when they should. But I realized a different strange behavior: When I start my main view, I see around 400 objects allocated, as soon as the view is displayed though, the allocation counter in Instruments increases suddenly to more than 6'000. Might be normal, so don't wanna start chasing phantoms again, if there is nothing to fix here. 
Thoughts? And are there maybe benchmarks available for such things? Wuld be quite helpful to understand that as the view itself of course also will create objects itself. Thanks.

Comment: The system frameworks themselves allocate quite a lot of small objects but as long as everything gets deallocated again no need to worry.